# Register Storage Class used in Socket Programming using C

Tags: c, sockets, gcc

What is the use of declaring file descriptor as register storage class in socket programming using c ?
If I am declared only int instead of register, then perror() returns "broken pipe". What is the meaning ?

example : register int i, s, len;

code copied from:
http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node28.html#SECTION002800000000000000000

socket_server.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NSTRS       3           /* no. of strings  */
#define ADDRESS     "mysocket"  /* addr to connect */

/*
 * Strings we send to the client.
 */
char *strs[NSTRS] = {
    "This is the first string from the server.\n",
    "This is the second string from the server.\n",
    "This is the third string from the server.\n"
};

main()
{
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    int fromlen;
    register int i, s, ns, len;
    struct sockaddr_un saun, fsaun;

    /*
     * Get a socket to work with.  This socket will
     * be in the UNIX domain, and will be a
     * stream socket.
     */
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("server: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Create the address we will be binding to.
     */
    saun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(saun.sun_path, ADDRESS);

    /*
     * Try to bind the address to the socket.  We
     * unlink the name first so that the bind won't
     * fail.
     *
     * The third argument indicates the "length" of
     * the structure, not just the length of the
     * socket name.
     */
    unlink(ADDRESS);
    len = sizeof(saun.sun_family) + strlen(saun.sun_path);

    if (bind(s, &saun, len) < 0) {
        perror("server: bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Listen on the socket.
     */
    if (listen(s, 5) < 0) {
        perror("server: listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Accept connections.  When we accept one, ns
     * will be connected to the client.  fsaun will
     * contain the address of the client.
     */
    if ((ns = accept(s, &fsaun, &fromlen)) < 0) {
        perror("server: accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * We'll use stdio for reading the socket.
     */
    fp = fdopen(ns, "r");

    /*
     * First we send some strings to the client.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < NSTRS; i++)
        send(ns, strs[i], strlen(strs[i]), 0);

    /*
     * Then we read some strings from the client and
     * print them out.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < NSTRS; i++) {
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            putchar(c);

            if (c == '\n')
                break;
        }
    }

    /*
     * We can simply use close() to terminate the
     * connection, since we're done with both sides.
     */
    close(s);

    exit(0);
}
```

socket_client.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NSTRS       3           /* no. of strings  */
#define ADDRESS     "mysocket"  /* addr to connect */

/*
 * Strings we send to the server.
 */
char *strs[NSTRS] = {
    "This is the first string from the client.\n",
    "This is the second string from the client.\n",
    "This is the third string from the client.\n"
};

main()
{
    char c;
    FILE *fp;
    register int i, s, len;
    struct sockaddr_un saun;

    /*
     * Get a socket to work with.  This socket will
     * be in the UNIX domain, and will be a
     * stream socket.
     */
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("client: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * Create the address we will be connecting to.
     */
    saun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(saun.sun_path, ADDRESS);

    /*
     * Try to connect to the address.  For this to
     * succeed, the server must already have bound
     * this address, and must have issued a listen()
     * request.
     *
     * The third argument indicates the "length" of
     * the structure, not just the length of the
     * socket name.
     */
    len = sizeof(saun.sun_family) + strlen(saun.sun_path);

    if (connect(s, &saun, len) < 0) {
        perror("client: connect");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * We'll use stdio for reading
     * the socket.
     */
    fp = fdopen(s, "r");

    /*
     * First we read some strings from the server
     * and print them out.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < NSTRS; i++) {
        while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            putchar(c);

            if (c == '\n')
                break;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Now we send some strings to the server.
     */
    for (i = 0; i < NSTRS; i++)
        send(s, strs[i], strlen(strs[i]), 0);

    /*
     * We can simply use close() to terminate the
     * connection, since we're done with both sides.
     */
    close(s);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. Just leaving out the `register` storage class does not lead to different code semantics. IOW the code works the same, with or without register. If it doesn't, your code was alreday broken (likely) or you compiler is broken (or the compile options) (unlikely).

Comment: I am working on eclipse-cdt. In that I used int instead of register than error occurred like "broken : piipe".

Comment: Yes Jens, Now I created same projects in eclipse-cdt, it is worked without register. But before that four times I tried than same error would occurred "broken : pipe".